# How to remove an URL protocol default handler

Tags: macos, protocol

I'm working on an application which should handle particular URL types (liked ed2k for emule or magnet for torrent). Recently, I decided to change this URL type from `abcd` to a more speakable word. Using RCDefaultApp, I'm able to change (or disable) the URL handler, but not to remove the protocol from the list. I was wondering how to delete that old entry. I'm using Mac OS X Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 6):

Edit `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist`in *Property List Editor* (part of Apple's developer tools) and remove the entry in `LSHandlers` with the `LSHandlerURLScheme` in question.

E.g. you'd select and delete *Item 12* if you wanted to remove `mailto` associations on my system:

[image]