# How to remove custom URL handlers in OS X?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, mac, url

I have an Electron app that has registered a custom url.  I checked the box "remember my decision" when I was prompted to open the external application while using Chrome (mac osx).

I now need to have that dialog re-appear.
**How would I un-register this url handling?**

I've tried deleting the item in the plist as hinted here:

- [How to remove an URL protocol default handler](https://superuser.com/questions/266023/how-to-remove-an-url-protocol-default-handler)
- [How do I configure custom URL handlers on OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/548119/how-do-i-configure-custom-url-handlers-on-os-x)

Deleting the line in the plist seems to just regenerate when I launch the app again.  I've also attempted changing the version of the app, but that didn't help either.

Has anyone had any luck re-engaging the dialog that asks the user "remember my preference" when opening a custom url handler?

Comment: Dammit, did they break RCDefaultApp? That gives me yet one more reason to stay on El Cap :/

Comment: Aye, I agree.  I really just need to do this for testing, seems some users don't push the "remember" checkbox and are experiencing some issues.  I need to do this to repeat their scenario.

Answer (score 4):

- Quit chrome
- Open "~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Preferences"
- Search for the "protocol_handler" entry
- Find the offending app/url. i.e.

  ```
    "https://miro.com":{"miroapp":true}
  ```
- change to

  ```
    "https://miro.com":{"miroapp":false}
  ```

(Guessing you could also remove)

- open chrome again and test.

Working in Chrome 87.0.4280.88